# Difference between "this" and "that" when referring to a previous sentence

Tags: word-choice, determiners, this-that

I have checked [this site](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/it-this.html).

> - We use ***this*** or ***that*** to refer to something with special emphasis – indicating an interesting new fact has been mentioned.
> - We use ***this*** or ***that*** to refer to a new topic, often the last thing mentioned. The reference could be a word, phrase or clause.

Are the uses of "this" and "that" below both grammatical? I think "that" also can be used in the sentences. I'd value your opinions.

Could any native speaker please answer this?

1. Apple is going to release a new operating system. ***This/that*** will be a huge step in merging the laptop OS with the iPad and iPhone OS.
2. AppleCar wants to market its auto in the United States first. **This/that** will allow the product to be tested before introducing it to the international market.
3. Heavy rains and stormy conditions throughout the summer have led to severe shortages in strawberries and other soft fruits. **This/that** has led to price rises in many supermarkets and shops

Comment: It's simple:  "this" is here and "that" is over there.

Comment: So, are you saying both are correct?

Comment: In all your examples it would be idiomatic to use 'this', referring to the fact that you have just stated.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. But is the use of that ungrammatical? I have checked this site https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/writing/it-this-and-that-in-paragraphs which says "We use 'that' in a similar way to "this'. However, when we use that, we distance ourselves more from the topic or from aspects of the topic".

Comment: In the examples, this/that stands in for the entire previous sentence, a vague reference. Better to say ‘that release,’ ‘that step,’ and ‘that shortage.’

Comment: "We use 'that' in a similar way to "this'. However, when we use that, we distance ourselves more from the topic or from aspects of the topic". That is exactly right.  Only sometimes the distances are figurative vs literal.  And it's up to the speaker to decide what's "close" and what's "far away".

Answer (score 2):

'This' has the sense of 'happening now'; 'that' has the sense of 'the effect once it is already completed' - along the lines of what others have said about 'distance'.

'That' is more impersonal and abstract, 'this' has more involvement and is livelier.

Hope this helps!  (Direct wish for now)
Hope that helped!  (More abstract impersonal wish thst doesn't really need an answer)

Answer (score -1):

"It" is the neutral personal pronoun.
"This" and "That" are demonstrative pronouns or adjectives.
"This" is related to the first person (the speaker).
"That" is related to the second or third person (you or he, others).
"It" can never be an adjective.